# the return type of decltype(function_name) is totally useless?

Tags: c++, function, declaration, decltype

```
void foo(int a) {
    cout << "Hello" << a << '\n';
}
```

according to rule of decltype, the type of decltype(foo) should be "void foo(int)",
but it seems we can do nothing with it:

```
void (& f_ref)(int) = foo;
void (* f_ptr)(int) = foo;


cout<<is_same_v<decltype(foo), decltype(f_ref)><<endl; //return 0
cout<<is_same_v<decltype(foo), decltype(f_ptr)><<endl; //return 0
decltype(foo) df;
df = foo;    //error: assignment of function ‘void df(int)’
df = &foo;   //error: assignment of function ‘void df(int)’

decltype(foo) df{foo}; //error: function ‘void df(int)’ is initialized like a variable
decltype(foo) df{&foo}; //error: function ‘void df(int)’ is initialized like a variable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two `is_same_v` in your snippets are evaluated as `0` because, well, the types are different.

`dectype(foo)` is `void (int)` (not `void foo(int)`, the name is not a part of the type),
which is different from `void (&)(int)` (the type of `f_ref`) and `void (*)(int)` (the type of `f_ptr`).

---

This line:

```
decltype(foo) df{foo};
```

doesn't compile just because the syntax doesn't allow you to have initializers in function declarations.

Even without the `decltype` it doesn't work:

```
void df(int) {foo}; // error: expected ';' before '}' token
```

Though you can create a pointer to `decltype(foo)`:

```
decltype(foo) *df{foo}; // Becomes `void (*df)(int) {foo};`
```

---

These lines:

```
df = foo;
df = &foo;
```

don't compile because you can't assign to functions. It wouldn't work even if `df` was `void df(int);`.

---

#### How can I use this type?

There are countless uses. E.g. you can use it to create pointers to this function as mentioned above, or it can be used as a template parameter (for `std::function` or something else).

Answer (score 2):

Declare a variable:

```
decltype(foo)* pf = foo;
pf(42);
```

Use a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) function wrapper:

```
std::function<decltype(foo)> f = foo;
f(42);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it to declare functional object that would have the same signature as a function:

```
using ffoo = ::std::function<decltype(foo)>;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is the return type of decltype(function_name) totally useless?

Definitely not. [Live example](https://ideone.com/2mZ4xl)

```
void f1();
void f2(int);
void f3();

int main()
{
    std::cout << "f1 - f2 " << std::is_same<decltype(f1),decltype(f2)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f1 - f3 " << std::is_same<decltype(f1),decltype(f3)>::value << std::endl;
}
```

this can be used with `std::enable_if` for example.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
cout<<is_same_v<decltype(foo), decltype(f_ref)><<endl;
```

the left template argument is a function type while the right template argument is a referenced type. To compare the types you should remove the reference.

In this statement

```
cout<<is_same_v<decltype(foo), decltype(f_ptr)><<endl;
```

there is compared a function type with a pointer to a function.

Thus the both statement returns 0 (false).

These statements

```
df = foo; 
df = &foo;
```

do not make sense. You may not assign functions.

And these statements

```
decltype(foo) df{foo}; 
decltype(foo) df{&foo};
```

also do not make sense.

You can declare a function of the type `decltype( foo )` for example in a class and then define it.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

void foo( int a ) 
{
    std::cout << "Hello " << a << '\n';
}

struct A
{
    decltype(foo) df;
};

void A::df( int a )
{
    std::cout << "Bye " << a << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    foo( 0 );
    A a;

    a.df( 1 );

    void (& f_ref)(int) = foo;
    void (* f_ptr)(int) = foo;

    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(&foo), decltype( f_ptr )>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(foo), std::remove_reference_t<decltype( f_ref )>>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello 0
Bye 1
1
1
```

Take into account that in this declaration

```
void (& f_ref)(int) = foo;
```

the function designator `foo` is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function.

Comment: so "decltype(foo) df;" actually declare a function, not a variable; in other words  "decltype(foo) df;" is equal to "void df(int);", right?

Comment: @camino Yes, it is.

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly as it should be. If you wrote `void(int) df;`, that is obviously wrong. You are attempting to declare a variable with a function type, which doesn't make sense. The only context where this might make sense is to declare a function object: `auto bar = std::function<decltype(foo)>;`
Now `bar` is an object which refers to a function (or function-like instance such as a lambda) with the type `void(int)`.

Comment: `decltype()` doesn't work like you think it does. E.g. `int a[5]; decltype(a) b;` compiles, even though `int[5] b;` does not.